# input type datetime-local is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have an input type of datetime-local which is working fine in chrome but when i try to run the same page in firefox it shows text box instead of datepicker.I have tried using modernizer but still the problem exist can anyone tell me how could the datetime-local issue can be fixed in firefox.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.basicInfoForm.validFrom.$invalid && (vm.basicInfoForm.validFrom.$dirty || vm.basicInfoForm.$submitted)}">
               <label translate >.NEW.STARTDATE</label>
               <input type="datetime-local" name="validFrom"  class="form-control" name="fromdate" ng-model="vm.basicInfo.validFrom"/>
               <span class="help-block error-block basic-block" translate>.NEW.CHECKDATE</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well, Firefox simply doesn't support datetime-local, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime, so basically, you're out of luck here.

Comment: You can - and please do! - add your vote to the somewhat obscure and weird bugtracker. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424984

Please note: To vote it's not enough to click the 'vote' button, you also have to tick the box and click the 'change my votes' on the next screen. Not easily visible either.

I've never seen a less user friendly voting system, but there it is.

Comment: Follow this issue for updates https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306217

Answer (score 22):

Is not supported, check their documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This is hilarious considering they have a article on their own page about that and how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local … they should really have such things implemented as its is a pretty basic html5 feature.

Comment: check the "Browser compatibility" section at the end of the article.

Comment: There are only 2 major browsers left unsupported. It is Firefox and Safari. And this topic is since 2018. Hmm.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal they never said this will be suported in the future, and it's documented FF doesn't support it,you shoulnd't be expecting anything new. More: https://caniuse.com/?search=datetime-local

Answer (score 8):

A [report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283388) was created for this issue on the official bug tracker. It was closed recently (< 1 month ago as of writing this) with the status `RESOLVED FIXED` and it has been implemented in the the [Firefox Nightly build (93.0a1 2021-09-02)](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/nightly/2021/09/).

With the above in mind, we should see this update rolled out soon, hopefully.

Example of `datetime-local` in the Nightly build:

[image: Example of datetime-local]

Example of visible picker in the Nightly build:

[image: Example of vsisible picker]

**Reading Material**

[Release Timeline](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Release_Process#Release_timeline)

Comment: Finaly... all the others major browsers already had this

Comment: I don't see time. This is suppposed to be date and time right

Comment: @Jar Me either. It seems like an incomplete implementation. I can see hour-min selector in Edge but not Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Input type "datetime-local" is not supported in Firefox hence it shows a text box, in this case, you can use input type as "date".

As "datetime-local" shows the time as well and if you have the same requirement, you can use Input type "time" also to show the time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox support for `datetime-local` is very limited and buggy, the info at "caniuse" and MDN is misleading.

Firefox does not support time-picker for the `datetime-local` input.

If the user picks date only - then the whole input return `null` as its `value`. Also, changing date only in the dropdown does not trigger `onchange` event.

They have an open bug about this for 2 years now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1726108