# ASP.Net MVC Tag Helper for DateTime not rendering in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a attribute call meeting time which is type `DateTime`.

model looks like this,

```
[Display(Name = "Meeting Time")]
public DateTime MeetingTime { get; set; }
```

view look like this

```
<div class="form-group mt-3">
     <label asp-for="MeetingTime"></label>
     <input asp-for="MeetingTime" id="MeetingTime" name="MeetingTime" class="form-control" onchange="validateMeetingDate()" />
     <span asp-validation-for="MeetingTime" class="text-danger"></span>
     <label id="dateError" style="display:none; color:#c90a14;">Start time is earlier than the current time</label>
</div>
```

in chrome it renders correctly, allowing user to pick date and the time. On Firefox its not showing the date-time picker.

[image: Chrome view]

On Firefox its render like this.

[image: Firefox view]

Date-picker of this example not working in Firefox. I am having the exact same issue. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thank you for the advice, I added the front end code as well.

Comment: @Brutus You haven't actually. Please show the HTML for the `<input>` tag that the browser receives.

Comment: Thanks for adding your server-side HTML, but it's still unclear what is rendering on the client-side.  The CSS class you show looks like perhaps it's from Bootstrap or some other library? If so, please recognize the problem is purely client-side, so C# is not relevant.  You'll need to tell us what libraries you're using to render the datepicker, including versions.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I am not using any client side library to render the date-piker. Its from asp .net mvc.

Comment: Still, please show the resulting `<input>` that the browser receives.

Comment: My guess is you are going to see an `<input type="datetime">` in the rendered html.  This was changed a long time ago for `<input type="datetime-local">`, since the former doesn't render in all browsers.  You likely need to upgrade your asp.net version.  See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4871

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Firefox [supports neither](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Comment: @GSerg `<input id="MeetingTime" name="MeetingTime" class="form-control valid" type="datetime-local" onchange="validateMeetingDate()" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Meeting Time field is required." value="" aria-describedby="MeetingTime-error" aria-invalid="false">`

Comment: I change the data type to datetime-local, but still the issue exists.

Comment: For example, this Mozilla example is not working on Firefox, I am having the exact same isuue. [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Comment: @Brutus Like I mentioned above, Firefox [currently only supports](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) `input type="date"` and `input type="time"`.

Comment: @GSerg - Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.  Perhaps someone has a polyfill or workaround to offer.  Also, I've updated the tags and title to draw more attention to this question.  Thanks.

Comment: So ultimately, [this explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567938/input-type-datetime-local-is-not-working-in-firefox), but it would still be good to see if anyone can provide a workaround with regard to ASP.Net MVC tag helpers.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041551/11683?